# Find a substring (filepath) from a string containing variable order arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

`%params%` contains a variable set of arguments:

`/tidy /log /truncate /convert D:\libdir`
or maybe

```
/log /tidy D:\cyclea\libfolder /test /convert /truncate
```

for everything but the (currently single) filepath element I use it such:

```
 if "%params%"=="%params:log=%" goto :DontLogit

   if NOT "%params%"=="%params:/tidy=%" (call tidysub: & do something else )
```

Now I want to extract the filepath element and use it as an argument to a command eg `chdir`

I've played with, but I'm weak with CMD string manipulation and `for` loops.

I'd like to keep the order of params variable.
For info it comes from here:

```
   FOR %%s IN (%*) DO (set params=!params! %%s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the single filepath element (with colon in second character):
set params=/tidy /log /truncate /convert D:\libdir
set filepath=
for %%a in (%params%) do (
   set par=%%a
   if "!par:~1,1!" == ":" (
      set filepath=%%a
   )
)
if defined filepath (
   echo Filepath = %filepath%
) else (
   echo Filepath not given
)
echo/

rem Get multiple filepath elements in an *array*:
set params=/log /tidy D:\cyclea\libfolder /test /convert D:\libdir /truncate
set i=0
for %%a in (%params%) do (
   set par=%%a
   if "!par:~1,1!" == ":" (
      set /A i+=1
      set filepath[!i!]=%%a
   )
)
echo There are %i% filepath elements:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do (
   echo %%i- !filepath[%%i]!
)
```

You may review a further description on array management at this post: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Aacini, many thanks. This is now in my code.  I had thought about the colon but couldn't think how to extract it.  The fact that it's always going to be there and in the 2nd char just didn't compute. Also I'd confused myself with potential filepaths starting ..\ etc.  Sometimes I just miss the obvious.  I actually won't be using the multi-filepath one; my brain was again over complicating things, but thanks it's filed away for just in case I need something similar.  Thanks again and all the best   Bill

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET swparams=log tidy test convert truncate
FOR %%i IN (%swparams% other) DO SET "%%i="
FOR %%i IN (%*) DO (
  SET "used="
  FOR %%p IN (%swparams%) DO (IF /i "/%%p"=="%%~i" SET %%p=Y&SET used=Y)
  IF NOT DEFINED used CALL SET other=%%other%% "%%~i"
  )

ECHO =============paramsreport===========
FOR %%i IN (%swparams%) DO IF DEFINED %%i (ECHO %%i:set) ELSE (ECHO %%i:clear)
ECHO other=%other%
FOR %%i IN (%other%) DO ECHO %%i or %%~i
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a way that should be extensible for you.

Simply set you switch-parameters into the list in swparams.

the parameter-names and OTHER are set to [nothing] to ensure they're not already set in the environment.
Ech supplied parameter is applied to %%i in turn, and matched against each defined swparam in turn. the variable `USED` is cleared before the match and if the match (of `/switchparametername` is found, the switch parameter is set and the USED flag is set.
if the used flag is not set gainst any of the switch parameters, then a parsing trick is used to accumulate any unrecognised strings into `OTHER`

The `"%%~i"` mechanism first dequotes the item in %%i, then quotes it. In this way, it ends up quoted, regardless of whether it originally has quotes or not.

The `/i` on the `if` performs a case-insensitive match.

hence running this batch

```
thisbatch /tidy "C:\some filename with spaces.txt"
```

will yield `TIDY` set to `Y`, `LOG`,`test`, `convert`, `truncate` not set and `other` set to `"C:\some filename with spaces.txt"`

Comment: Thanks for this Peter and sorry for the delay in responding.